# Django Cannot assign "x'": "y" must be a "z.`

Tags: python, django

I am receiving the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /change_chosenCharity/

ValueError at /change_chosenCharity/
Cannot assign "19L": "Profile.chosenCharity" must be a "Charity" instance.
```

From the following view:

```
@login_required
def change_chosenCharity(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = updateCharity(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            currentUser = request.user
            currentUserID = currentUser.id
            chosenCharityQuery = Charity.objects.filter(id=request.POST['currentCharities'])
            charity_id = chosenCharityQuery[0].id
            created = Profile.objects.update_or_create(
                user_id=currentUserID,
                defaults={'chosenCharity': charity_id},
            )
            messages.success(request, 'Your chosen charity has been updated.')
            return redirect(reverse('profile'))
    else:
        form = updateCharity()
    return render(request, 'meta/changechosencharity.html', {'form': form})
```

The post result from Django shows:

```
POST:
currentCharities = u'19'
```

19 is definitely an instance of the charity.  I have had this issue before and always solved it relatively quickly.  I have searched on here but can't find a solution for my issue.  Any help would be appreciated.

**Additional Info:**

HTML FORM:

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">{{ form.currentCharities.label }}:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          {{ form.currentCharities }}
          <div class="text-danger">
            {% for error in form.currentCharities.errors %}{{ error }}<br/>{% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="text-right col-sm-12">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change Charity</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

DJANGO MODEL:

```
class Charity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    website = models.URLField()
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name_plural = 'charities'
```

FORM:

```
class updateCharity(BootstrapForm):

    currentCharities = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Charity.objects.filter(enabled=1), empty_label=None,widget=forms.Select(attrs={"class": "select-format"}))
    currentCharities.label = "Charity Options"


    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data # individual field's clean methods have already been called
        return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either update the related object instance:

```
charity = chosenCharityQuery[0]
created = Profile.objects.update_or_create(
            user_id=currentUserID,
            defaults={'chosenCharity': charity},
        )
```

Or update the id of the related field:

```
charity_id = chosenCharityQuery[0].id
created = Profile.objects.update_or_create(
            user_id=currentUserID,
            defaults={'chosenCharity_id': charity_id},
        )
```